# Limit the number of pages

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to generate a pdf from the html content which has been entered using the mpdf library.

Is there any possibilities of limiting the number of pages.
For example: I want only two pages not more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the maximum number of pages, you simply add a fixed maximum number of pages programmatically after having set the page size.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4');
```

so now you have A4 pages, now you add the specified number of pages.

If instead you want to use html as a long line of text

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div id="text"><p>Bla bla</p></div>', 2);
```

you might need to measure somehow how long your html is based on the page format, that might not be as easy as it sounds.

Comment: thanks alot dendhini. This code$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div id="text"><p>Bla bla</p></div>', 2); dont work out for me

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can override mpdf class addPage method, and if the number of pages is more then you want, generate EnoughPagesException, catch it up in your code, and there you have the mpdf object with the number of pages you need.

Comment: Thanks alot marek for your response. However i am worried about limiting the content to only one page. For example if i enter html content which gets converted into 5 equilent pages, then i want it to show only one page not all the the 5 pages. I mean i want the only one page content.